# What methods can be used to determine the Order of Integration of a time series?

Tags: time-series

Econometricians often talk about a time series being *integrated with order k, I(k)*. *k* being the minimum number of differences required to obtain a stationary time series.

What methods or statistical tests can be used to determine, given a level of confidence, the *order of integration* of a time series?

Answer (score 18):

There are a number of statistical tests (known as "unit root tests") for dealing with this problem. The most popular is probably the "Augmented Dickey-Fuller" (ADF) test, although the Phillips-Perron (PP) test and the KPSS test are also widely used.

Both the ADF and PP tests are based on a null hypothesis of a unit root (i.e., an I(1) series). The KPSS test is based on a null hypothesis of stationarity (i.e., an I(0) series). Consequently, the KPSS test can give quite different results from the ADF or PP tests.

Comment: Is there a convenient way to determine the order of integration if beyond I(0) or I(1), e.g. I(2) etc.?

Comment: Difference the data and apply the tests again.

Answer (score 4):

Also, for some elaborate discussion (including bashing of ADF / PP / KPSS :) you might want to have a look at the book by Maddala and Kim:

[http://www.amazon.com/Cointegration-Structural-Change-Themes-Econometrics/dp/0521587824](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521587824)

Quite extensive and not very easy to read sometimes, but a useful reference.